# UnityでandroidのonActivityResultで取得した結果を取得する方法について

Tags: unity3d

いつもお世話になっております。

UnityでAndroidJavaObject経由でonActivityResultの結果取得方法についての質問となります。

やりたいことは以下となります。

1. Unity(C#)から以下のコードでAndroidJavaコードをコールする

```
using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
            using (AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic("currentActivity")) {
                using (AndroidJavaClass cls = new AndroidJavaClass ("hoge.QRCodeReader")) {
                    cls.CallStatic ("readQRCode", activity);
                }
            }
        }
```

2. 以下のJavaが呼び出される

```
package hoge;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class QRCodeReader extends Activity {

    public String result = "";

    public static void readQRCode(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        // バーコード："ONE_D_MODE"、QRコード："QR_CODE_MODE"、両方："MODE"
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
        try {
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Uri url = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
            activity.startActivity(intent2);
        }
    }

    public String getResultCOde() {
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if( requestCode == 42 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            result = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            Log.e("hogehoge", "@@@@@@@: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

ここまでをAndroidの実機で実行すると、確かに、QRコードreaderアプリが呼び出されます。
しかし、次にやりたいことは

3. startActivityForResultで呼び出されたバーコードアプリで読み込んだバーコードテキストをonActivityResultで受け取る
4. 3で受け取ったバーコードテキストをUnity側に返す

です。
しかし、Unity側にonActivityResultで取得されたバーコードテキストを返す方法がどうしてもわかりません。

お手数ですが、お知恵を拝借できればと存じます。

何卒、宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AndroidJavaProxyを用いて、onActivityResultのタイミングでJava側からコールバックを呼び出すようにしてはいかがでしょうか。

参考SDK Doc：
http://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaProxy.html

Comment: ありがとうございます！確かにこちらでいけそうですね！
ただ、以下に追記で投稿させて頂いたのですが、うまくいかず。。何かアドバイス等をいただけましたら幸いです。。

Answer (score -1):

アドバイスありがとうございます！

早速使ってみました。

```
public class QRCodeReader extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    private QRCodeListener listener;


    public void setListener(QRCodeListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void readQRCode(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        // バーコード："ONE_D_MODE"、QRコード："QR_CODE_MODE"、両方："MODE"
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
        try {
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Uri url = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
            activity.startActivity(intent2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String result = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        data.putExtra("barcode", result);
        if(listener != null) {
            listener.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

リスナーは以下です。

```
public interface QRCodeListener {
    public void onRestart();

    public void onStart();

    public void onResume();

    public void onPause();

    public void onStop();

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
}
```

C#は以下です！

```
public class UnityAdd : MonoBehaviour {

    public void ShowAd() {
        using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
            using (AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) {
                using (AndroidJavaClass cls = new AndroidJavaClass ("hoge.QRCodeReader")) {
                    cls.Call("setListener", new ActivityListener());
                    Debug.Log ("hoge");
                    cls.CallStatic ("readQRCode", activity);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ActivityListener : AndroidJavaProxy
    {
        public ActivityListener()
            : base("hoge.QRCodeListener")
        {
        }

        public void onRestart()
        {
        }

        public void onStart()
        {
        }

        public void onResume()
        {
        }

        public void onPause()
        {
        }

        public void onStop()
        {
        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, AndroidJavaObject data)
        {
            Debug.Log (data.Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("getStringExtra", "barcode", "なし"));
        }
    }
}
```

やってみたのですが、登録したcallbackが呼ばれない状態でハマっております。
実機でしか確認ができず、実機debugしながら動きの確認をしておりますが、Unity(C#)で登録した方のonActivityResultが呼ばれない状況となります。

何か勘違い、書き間違いなどございますでしょうか？？

お手数ですが、もしアドバイス等、ご助力いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score -1):

何ができていないかわかりました。

まず、上記コードの問題は
・QRCodeReaderはインスタンス生成して呼ぶものではない(Activityなので)。
・callStaticでなく、callで呼ぶべき

```
using (AndroidJavaClass cls = new AndroidJavaClass ("hoge.QRCodeReader")) {
            cls.Call("setListener", new ActivityListener());
            Debug.Log ("hoge");
            cls.CallStatic ("readQRCode", activity);
        }
```

・CurrentActivityにはAndroidManifestに記載してある「UnityPlayerActivity」が呼ばれる。

なので、やらなくてはならないことは

・AndroidManifestのmain Activityを「QRCodeReader」に書き換える
・CurrentActivityが上記QRCodeReaderになるので、

```
using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
    using (AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) {
        activity.Call("setListener", new ActivityListener());
        activity.CallStatic ("readQRCode", activity);
    }
}
```

とすべきということ。

ですが、/Temp/StagingArea/AndroidMnifest.xmlの書き換えがうまくいきません。
Assets/Plugins/Android下にAndroidManifestを追加してbuild時にmergeさせるのですが、
その時にmergeに失敗します。
しかも、他のlibの「unityAds」の「UnityAdsFullscreenActivity」の記載箇所でエラーが出ます。。

Comment: 解決しました！単純な記載ミスでした。